# error: failed to read input object (not a Template?): error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Tags: java, json, yaml

What does this error mean? Is it due to indentation? Is there any way to auto align yaml files

I tried fixing it by aligning etc but it didn't work and my jenkins build is failing.

```
- name: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN
   valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
        name: splunk-secret
        key: splunk.token
- name: SPLUNK_LOG_URL             //error in this line
   valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
       name: splunk-config
       key: splunk.url
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is invalid YAML (in both items):

```yaml
- name: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN
   valueFrom:
```

This is because `valueFrom` is more indented than `name`. Thus YAML thinks that `valueFrom` is a continuation of the scalar `SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN`. However, a `:` follows which ends an implicit mapping key. And implicit mapping keys are forbidden in a multi-line scalar context, hence the error.

> Is there any way to auto align yaml files

Indentation in YAML is part of the semantic (like in Python). You are basically asking whether you can *guess* the intended semantic for badly indented files. While this is theoretically not impossible (I mean, you *could* train a neural network on YAML syntax questions on StackOverflow; I have seen this particular problem countless times), I don't think a readily usable solution exists.

The probable solution for your problem is

```yaml
- name: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN
 valueFrom:
```

however, I can't be 100% sure; perhaps you rather want to do something like

```yaml
- name:
    id: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN
    valueFrom:
```

if `valueFrom` should be a child of `name`.

Answer (score 2):

The highlighted one is the invalid yaml pattern's.
`- name: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN` `- name: SPLUNK_LOG_URL`.

It should be something like this

```
- name: 
   name: SPLUNK_LOG_TOKEN
   valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
        name: splunk-secret
        key: splunk.token
- name:             
   name: SPLUNK_LOG_URL 
   valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
       name: splunk-config
       key: splunk.url
```

If you are JSON lover like me, then you can try this online converter https://www.json2yaml.com/convert-yaml-to-json

When I was new to yaml, I used to write smaller chunks of JSON data and get it converted using the online https://www.json2yaml.com/convert-yaml-to-json into YAML format.
There are also other tools available online, but from personal experience I preferred this.